# There's a question that has no answer; should I ask it again or start a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, asking-questions

I need to know the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558288/multiple-accounts-with-refinerycms). I thought that I should start a bounty, but I don't have high rep, far less than the original asker.

Can I ask it again? Or should I start a bounty?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> but I don't have a high rep, far less than the original asker

Why does that matter? You have enough to set a bounty. Why would the asker's rep matter for setting a bounty?

> can I ask it again?

No, it would be closed as a duplicate.

> should I start a bounty?

If you really want an answer, then yes.

Note that the question has 3 close votes as "too broad," so **in this specific case** you *could* just ask a narrower version of the question. There are 3 questions in one in that post; you may consider narrowing the problem down and adding more details. However, in cases like this where the question is exactly what you want, a bounty is the way to go.

Comment: Them's mighty educated words for a chatbot

Comment: @Pëkka I need rep to talk in chat :P

Comment: There's another issue , it's 1 year old and lots have changed since then